# my ajax call not working..no value is being returned from php file

Tags: php, ajax

```
<label id="myInput">12345678910</label>
<label id="cno">Certificate Number :</label>
<label id="mon">Made On :</label> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myInput').click(function(){
    var x=document.getElementById("myInput").innerHTML;
    alert(x);
    $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'process.php',
    data: 'cid='+x,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(reply_data){
        $('#mon').innerHTML(reply_data);
        $('#cno').innerHTML(reply_data['Cno']);
    }   
}); 
});
</script>
```

The PHP file is:

```
<?php
require 'dbl.php';



function clean($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['cid'])) 
{

$sno=clean($_REQUEST['cid']);
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from certi_details where Cno='$sno'");
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if(empty($rows))
{
     echo "hellooooo";
}
else
{
    $arr=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
}
?>
```

`alert(x)` is working correctly, so I think the value is being sent to the PHP file, but nothing is returned as nothing is being printed in both the labels (`cno` and `mon`).

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending data in incorrect format. You should use `data: {'cid':x}`.